# Template is not rendering form

Tags: django

forms.py

```
class password_reset(forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'palceholder':' type password'})
    password2 = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'type password again'})

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password Mismatch')
        return data
```

views.py

```
def password_resetView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = password_reset(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            obj = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
            obj.set_password(password)
            obj.save()
            form.save()
    else:
        form = password_reset()
    return render(request,'password_reset.html',{'form':form})
```

template

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

so i cant able to render form in template.. no error showing, its rendering to the respective html but doesnt render the form.

Comment: Note, for a password change form you probably want the user to enter their existing password, which you can verify with `request.user.check_password()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, i will add it .. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using widget instead of field. You have to use a `CharField` with the `PasswordInput` widget.

```
password1 = forms.CharField(attrs={'placeholder': 'type password'}, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(attrs={'placeholder': 'type password again'}, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```